# Keyboard/Mouse not working when windows vista has reached login screen

Tags: windows, windows-vista, drivers, login

I currently have a problem with a system (vista home premium, 64bit). USB kbd/mouse will not work when windows has booted/loaded their drivers and Im stuck at the login screen with no working input devices. None of the available boot options after F8 will boot to working kbd/mouse.

They work in the bios setup and they seem powered all the way until a few seconds before the login screen. Legacy USB devices is also enabled in the bios.

They also work with the recovery dvd, but I am unable to start the device manager to check or uninstall the mouse/kbd drivers. Cant get devmgmt.msc nor devmgr.dll (with rundll32) to work.

System repair does not detect the problem and there are no available restore points (it was disabled).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do they work in safe mode?

Comment: No, no boot option with F8 works

Comment: Does it work at all?  Allow you into the system bios and move around for instance?

Comment: This is likely a USB driver problem.  Use a non-usb keyboard.

Comment: They work in bios/cmos.

Comment: Yes, Its a driver problem, I just could not get into devmgr with the repair dvd. After a lot of tests, I managed to use regsvr32 to get most of the com-objects registered to use devmgmt and disable a driver from Merc Stealth that was causing the primary usb hub to stop working. That driver was, according to the owner, released through win update. I suspect either a failed/interrupted install or faulty driver. I got the system running now, no thanks to Vistas recovery dvd. Xp was so much better ;)